# Bidirectional links to the same class in Entity Framework (code first)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I would like to create bidirectional links to the same class. Id like for the relationship class to have the attributes that would explain how the two classes are related. It may be a parent-child relationship or it be a simple "reference" relationship.

Currently, if I use the setup below, Entity Framework will automatically create a 3rd foreign key in the link table for the "myChildNodes" relationship. The only way I can get Entity Framework to understand what I am trying to do on the link class is to create two collections I.E. (childOf and ParentOf).

I would like to dynamically add relationship types and not need to create a collection representing that relationship type. I would rather handle that in the repository for the node object.

```
Node
{
    Public int id {get; set;}
    Public datetime createDate {get; set;}
    Public bool isModified {get; set;}

    //I would like just one collection for all links from this node as the source node
    Public virtual ICollection<Link> myChildNodes{get; set;}

    //I don't want to use something like this that explicitly defines the relationship
    //Public virtual ICollection<Node> parentOf{get; set;}
    //Public virtual ICollection<Node> childOf{get; set;}

    Public Node() {
    }
}

Link { 
    Public int id {get; set;}
    Public datetime createdDate {get; set;}
    Public string linkType {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("SourceNode")]
    Public int? SourceNodeId { get; set;}

    Public Node SourceNode {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("TargetNode")]
    Public int? TargetNodeId { get; set;}

    Public Node TargetNode {get; set;}

    Public Link() {
    }
}
```

Has anyone had success with this design before?

Comment: *I don't want to use something like this that explicitly defines the relationship* Well, then you should not be using EF. Entities are supposed to represent the data model and relationships, not the domain or business object model. You have 2 Link to Node navigation properties (SourceNode and TargetNode), so the entity model requires you to have 2 Node to Link collections - SourceLInks and TargetLinks. Simply as that. No options. Period.

Comment: It is not the data model and relationships between classes that I am trying to keep flexible. I know that two Nodes will be linked by a Link, and that the link table will have two Foreign keys to the Node Table. It is the business logic that I need to keep flexible.

I do understand now that 2 navigation properties is going to yield 2 collections. It makes sense. The collection needs to know which key to traverse for the data its looking for. I would still argue that the business need makes sense and shouldn't result in dismissing EF as the framework of choice.